# How can we convert script tags to AMP for a complete webpage

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I am having webpage comprised of multiple external CSS, external js and jQuery placed in the html file only. I want to covert my whole page to AMP. Is it possible ? I have seen tutorial and found that script tag are allowed to be converted to AMP. Can I change following script tag to AMP ? If yes, how?

```
  <script src="./MyWebsite_files/jquery.flexslider.js.download"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide"
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
   function contclick(){
        $(".mov-etm").hide();
   }

   $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
   } );
</script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
  {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
       Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
         [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
     })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
        analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

     ga('create', 'UA-20183208-1', 'auto');
     ga('send', 'pageview');

 </script>
```

help is appreciated. I am totally new for this AMP thing.

Comment: What do you mean by AMP? Accelerated Mobile Pages? Or what?

Comment: @Rikvola Yes, I mean Accelerated Mobile Pages

Comment: Already checked out this one? 
https://www.ezoic.com/google-amp-converter/# 
This was only the first record which I found on Google... 
Did you even search something? This isn't a page where others do your work.

Comment: @joshii_h Bro I did search on Google. Thanks for the suggestion, also I have been through the link you provided. But my question is different!!

Comment: You cannot have your own JavaScript code on AMP pages at all, you can only use the JavaScript modules provided by the AMP project

Comment: @PatrickHund Thanks a lot. I understand. But Is there any way of using those scripts in AMP. For example , I have a webpage that I need to be converted into AMP, but my webpage contains lot of scripting code and jQuery Code, than is there a way to use those scripts, or can we build a custom scripts using AMP?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided you can use AMP-components that are available that will achieve you goal.

- For the slider you can use [amp-carousel](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel/)
- For the Google analytics code use [amp-analytics](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics)
- For the date picker, there does not seem
  to be anything specific but I recommend you checkout
  [ampbyexample.com](https://ampbyexample.com) as there maybe components that will do what you
  want.

While it is true that you cannot include script tags directly on an AMP page, one can add a script to the page using a service worker. But this is a rather complex pattern that is intended for Progressive Web-Apps and not for adding components.[amp-install-serviceworker](https://www.ampproject.org/es/docs/reference/components/amp-install-serviceworker).

You can also add interactive content using an i-frame, that may be what you need for the date picker [How to embed interactive elements on AMP pages?](https://ampbyexample.com/dynamic_amp/how_to_embed_interactive_elements_on_amp_pages/)